# Android pending request

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I have such situation:
I have changed some info in app without internet and I need update it info on server when the Internet appears. What is the best practice to make pending request? How to store a queue of requests?
P.S. I use Retrofit.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your architecture. But I prefer using some Executor([ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)) that runs under service. Each task has stage. if it crashed on some stage. it will be pushed back into the queue. And next time it continue from failed stage. At the same time each task should use data for execute only from [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). so each task should be initiated with Bundle (like Fragment setBundle) So your executor will has posibility to store task in database, or just in runtime, depends on your aproach/project.

**EDIT:**
Save to DB
It depends. Do you want just to renew all failed tasks, or make then something with them? for example renew only ones that was failed 1 hour ago, maybe you have same date fields in each request, etc. SO it's up to you. But since your tasks storing all data into Parcel, you have general way. Just put it into ObjectOutputStream. then you could read it. Also you could disassemble your Bundle manualy and store it to different columns.

Comment: Can you show example how to store such task in database?